# JoomlaLMS change default language according to User

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a system where the Users have different default languages, set in the Joomla Administrator (Portuguese, English and Spanish).
When a user enter the JoomlaLMS section, the default language of the LMS should automatically change.
Today, the site have a drop down menu to select the language:

```
function jlms_changeLang() {
    var user_lang = $('jlms_lang').value;
    window.top.location.href='<?php echo str_replace('__lang__', "'+user_lang+'", $JLMS_CONFIG->getCfg('live_site')."/index.php?option=$option&Itemid=$Itemid&task=user_lang&course_id=$id&lang=__lang__")?>';
}
```

Anybody already did this? I have no clue what to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way!
The LMS default lannguage is stored in the page SESSION
So, in my index, i've just manually setted the right value getting the right parammeter from the database.
If anyone need, the SESSION variable is:

```
$_SESSION['lms_user_language']
```

=D

Answer (score 0):

JoomlaLMS source code isn't open for changes (except Professional version) You can freely contact JoomlaLMS development team and ask for customization. It is a regular practice for them. support@joomlalms.com

Comment: Thanks, but i've figured it out! =)